# Rails 3 Cleaning up repeated syntax for displaying object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

So I'm mapping an object's attributes to a table within a view and I wanted to make the code a little more succinct and eliminate redundant HTML.

Here's what it looks like:

```
- @users.each do |user|
   %tr
     %td= user.username
     %td= user.first_name
     %td= user.last_name
     %td= user.email
     %td= user.country
     %td= user.state
     %td= user.password 
      ...
```

I was wondering if there was a good way to eliminate all of those redundant `%td= user.` calls. I was watching the Railscast episode on [Form Builders](http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders?view=asciicast) and he had a helper method that uses the following meta-programming syntax to eliminate repeats:

```
%w[text_field text_area password_field collection_select].each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) do |name, *args|
```

Now is there any way I can use something similar to this structure? I actually tried to implement this exact syntax structure after replacing the method names and it seems that the define_method function was undefined (oh the irony!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.send` to invoke a method dynamically:

```
- %w(username first_name last_name ...).each do |method|
  %td= user.send(method)
```